# How to install folium 0.5.0+115.g53bf936 in python 3.6.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, folium

I want to learn folium with the following documation

https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/index.html

But when I use pip install found that only have version 0.5.0 in Windows command

[image: folium version found]

Does someone know about this question?

I want the latest version  because I got a problem with its function **markers**

```
m = folium.Map(
location=[45.372, -121.6972],
zoom_start=12,
tiles='Stamen Terrain'
)

tooltip = 'Click me!'

folium.Marker([45.3288, -121.6625], popup='<i>Mt. Hood Meadows</i>', 
tooltip=tooltip).add_to(m)
folium.Marker([45.3311, -121.7113], popup='<b>Timberline Lodge</b>', 
tooltip=tooltip).add_to(m)

m
```

[image]

Comment: ```sudo -H pip install folium``` didn't work ?

Comment: @Rahul Bharadwaj  yeah but the version doesn't match with the documation

Comment: Upon doing `folium.__version__` I get `0.5.0` . Can you link the documentation ?

Comment: Oh, it's the same version, they are just being specific with their builds. Do what the doc says, it installs 0.5.0 by default.

If you want to install a specific commit from their git then you'll have to build the packages by yourself, which will be a bit time consuming. Or you can clone the specific commit and create a local env around it and use it locally.

Comment: @Rahul Bharadwaj the documation link is in the article, it use folium version is  0.5.0+115.g53bf936

Comment: Yes I see that. The extra stuff after 0.5.0 might be their build numbers or commit numbers, just some extra information showing it's a stable build. Do as the doc says, `pip install folium` .

Comment: @Rahul Bharadwaj  so I can get the latest version from github to instead?
https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/tree/master/folium

Comment: You can, but it may not be stable. If you know how to build python packages by yourself, then go ahead. Else you may break your python installation. But since you are on windows, I guess it doesn't matter because you can reinstall python and start over afresh.

Comment: I see but I have the question about its function just post in the article, that copy from documation